# Finding Duplicates in Array and printing them only Once

Tags: java, arrays, file, for-loop, duplicates

I am trying to loop through my array and find all the numbers that are repeating more than once:

E.G: if there is `1 1 2 3 4`

It should print saying "1 repeats more than once"

Here is my code and so far what I have tried, however it prints all duplicates and keep going, if there is `4 4 4 4 3 6 5 6 9`, it will print all the 4's but i dont want that:

```
class average {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int numOfLines = 0;
    int sum = 0, mean = 0, median = 0, lq = 0, uq = 0;
    int[] buffer;

    File myFile = new File("num.txt");
    Scanner Scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    while(Scan.hasNextLine()) {
        Scan.nextLine();
        numOfLines++;
    }
    Scan.close();
    Scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    System.out.println("Number Of Lines: " + numOfLines);

    buffer = new int[numOfLines];

    for(int i=0; i<numOfLines; i++) {
        buffer[i] = Scan.nextInt();
    }
    Scan.close();
    Scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
        sum = sum+i;
        mean = sum/numOfLines;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);

    for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
        for(int k=i+1; k<buffer.length; k++) {
            if(buffer[k] == buffer[i]) {
                System.out.println(buffer[k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the array?

Comment: I'm trying to do it without Sorting @Makoto

Comment: Can you use a `Set`?

Comment: That's fair.  In that case, do you know the range of values you have after you've read them in?  That is, do you know the minimum and maximum values?  That can help you in this case.

Comment: @Kon - No sets, just simple array

Comment: @Makoto - The file just contains the following numbers **1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 7, 9, 1, 1, 3**

Comment: I'm not talking about inferential data.  If you were supplied a different file, could you calculate the range of numbers you get?  I have an idea that would lead you in the right direction, but having the ability to get the range is *critical*.

Comment: @GDesigns you want no sorting or use of any collection.  Just use of arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the number you will find duplicated to some structure like `HashSet` or `HashMap` so you can find it later when you will detect another duplication.

```java
Set<Integer> printed = new HashSet<Integer>();

  for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
    for(int k=i+1; k<buffer.length; k++) {
      if(buffer[k] == buffer[i]) {
        Integer intObj = new Integer(buffer[k]);
        if (!printed.contains(intObj)) {
          System.out.println(buffer[k]);
          printed.add(intObj);
        }
        break;
       }
    }
  }
```

**Better O(n) alghorithm:**

```java
Set<Integer> printed = new HashSet<Integer>();

  for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
    if (!printed.add(new Integer(buffer[i])) {
       System.out.println(buffer[i]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have O(n^2), can be reduced to O(n) by eliminating the second loop.

Comment: No need to create `Integer` instance due to autoboxing -> `printed.Add(buffer[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

You perform the check for every single item of the array, including the first `4`, the second `4` and so on. That's why it just doesn't stop and it prints the message multiple times per duplicated element.

You're saying you cannot use a `Set` and that you don't want to sort your data. My suggestion is that you loop over the array and add each duplicated item to a list. Make sure you check whether the item has already been added. (or use a `Set` :) )

Then loop over the list and print those items.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `HashMap` to store the value I encounter in the array, with the count as a value.  So if you encounter a 4, you would look it up in the `HashMap`, if it doesn't exist, you would add it with a value of 1, otherwise increment the value returned.

You can the loop over the `HashMap` and get all the values and print the number of duplicates encountered in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **apache commons** CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap(collection):

```
  final Integer[] buffer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 7, 9, 1, 1, 3};
  final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(buffer);
  final Map<Integer, Integer> cardinalityMap = CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap(list);
  for (final Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry: cardinalityMap.entrySet()) {
    if (entry.getValue() > 1) {
      System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
  }
```

toString() of cardinalityMap looks like this after the init:

```
{1=4, 2=2, 3=2, 4=1, 5=1, 6=1, 7=2, 9=1}
```

Using **standard java**:

```
  final Integer[] buffer = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 7, 9, 1, 1, 3};
  final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(buffer);
  final Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(list);
  for (final Integer element: set) {
    if (Collections.frequency(list, element) > 1) {
      System.out.println(element);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] ints = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4};

System.out.println(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(ints)));
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is much simpler and likely faster to solve using a collection. However, as requested here's an answer that uses "just simple array[s]" and no sorting.  I've tried not to change your code too much but I refuse to leak resources in the case of an exception.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Average {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int numOfLines = 0;
        int sum = 0, mean = 0, median = 0, lq = 0, uq = 0;
        int[] buffer;
        int flag = -1;

        File myFile = new File("num.txt");
        try (Scanner Scan = new Scanner(myFile)) {

            while(Scan.hasNextLine()) {
                Scan.nextLine();
                numOfLines++;
            }
        }
        try (Scanner Scan = new Scanner(myFile)) {

            System.out.println("Number Of Lines: " + numOfLines);

            buffer = new int[numOfLines];

            for(int i=0; i<numOfLines; i++) {
                buffer[i] = Scan.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
            sum = sum+i;
            mean = sum/numOfLines;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        System.out.println("Mean: " + mean);

        //copy every duplicate
        int[] dupesOnly = new int[numOfLines];
        int dupesOnlyIndex = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<buffer.length; i++) {
            for(int k=i+1; k<buffer.length; k++) {
                if(buffer[k] == buffer[i]) {
                    dupesOnly[dupesOnlyIndex++] = buffer[i];
                    //System.out.println(buffer[k]);
                }
            }
        }

        //mark all but first occurrence of dupe
        boolean[] skip = new boolean[dupesOnlyIndex]; //Inits to false
        for (int i = 0; i < dupesOnlyIndex; i++) {
            for(int k=i+1; k<buffer.length; k++) {
                if(dupesOnly[k] == dupesOnly[i]) {
                    skip[k] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //skip elements marked as extra dupes
        int[] dupesUnique = new int[dupesOnlyIndex];
        int dupesUniqueIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dupesOnlyIndex; i++) {
            if (skip[i] == false) {
                dupesUnique[dupesUniqueIndex++] = dupesOnly[i];
            }
        }     

        //trim to size
        int[] dupesReport = new int[dupesUniqueIndex];
        for (int i = 0; i < dupesReport.length; i++) {
            dupesReport[i] = dupesUnique[i];
        }

        System.out.println("Dupes: " + Arrays.toString(dupesReport));
    }
}
```

Input file "num.txt" (numbers separated by newlines not commas):

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 7, 9, 1, 1, 3
```

Output:

```
Number Of Lines: 14
Sum: 91
Mean: 6
Dupes: [1, 2, 3, 7]
```